# Download failed at VideoColorizerColab.ipynb-Coloaboratory

Tags: colorize

Here's the message I get with deatils about the fail.

```
Download failed
Could not fetch resource at https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/gpu-p100-s-1nsim9mlahjyh/files/content/DeOldify/video/result/video.mp4?authuser=5: 504 
FetchError: Could not fetch resource at https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/gpu-p100-s-1nsim9mlahjyh/files/content/DeOldify/video/result/video.mp4?authuser=5: 504 
    at Lz.Kz [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20191219-082400-RC00_286397102:911:76)
    at new Lz (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20191219-082400-RC00_286397102:911:293)
```

Since 2 days this web can only communicate with the google drive, if I make a copy of the video and share that one.  After the colorization process finished, as usual the connect with the runtime breakes and a few moments later it connects back and I can find the mp4 result in the deoldify folder. Now it all gets disappeared, so the whole session gets lost. I tried with 2 minutes video segment. Strangely also pops up a messge that failed to runtime, but after it reconnects the session will be found. What happeded, can't I use 7 or 8 minutes video segments anymore or the servers are too busy these days?  Please help me about my problem!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and after few researches i found a solution that may help.

if you're using Firefox, try to use google chrome instead.
If you're using google chrome, go in the settings, then search for "reset" (there's a search bar above), and reset google chrome.

it worked for me.